# how to use common session in different application

Tags: java, spring, session, google-cloud-platform

I'm using two applications(A,B) hosted on different domains with common Db, when user login in A site suppose if he clicks B site I pass unique ID which matches with table and sets user session in B site, at this time existing session in A sites gets null if I open A website in another tab.

Comment: I think we'll need a little more information to help you. How do you pass the unique ID to application B? How do you recreate the session in B? How do you maintain the session ID on the client-side? With a cookie? Or a parameter added to the URL?

Comment: When user login to site A we create unique token/ID and update in users  table, when user click site B i sent unique token/ ID by url which is used to recreate session in site B. session ID is maintained in cookie not added to URL.